# Updating MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have MS SQL Server Management Studio installed on the server. It's 6.2.9200 version.

There is a new version of MS SQL Server Management Studio 6.3.9600.

How should I update the MS SQL Server Management Studio from 6.2.9200 to 6.3.9600? Shall simply install the .MSI and the studio updates to the latest version or should I take some kind of back-up for the 6.2.9200 before installing 6.3.9600?

Comment: "*should I take some kind of back-up"* - it is completely up to you.

Comment: Why are you worrying? It's only the client tool.

Comment: How can we take a back-up for SQL Server Management Studio? @AndyKorneyev

Comment: @MattGibson Will it be perfectly okay if I just install the new version of MS SQL Server Management Studio over the existing version? It upgrade without any issues? I'm doing it for the first time so just wanted to be careful.

Comment: Well, I couldn't guarantee it. My point is that it's not that important. You could delete the entire management studio installation and reinstall it if you wanted -- what are you thinking of backing up? The user settings, or something?

Comment: @MattGibson At the moment I use SQL Server Authentication mode (sa and password) and we have only one/this user. When I reinstall studio will that  user be retained or do I need to create the sa user again? I am not sure if MS SQL Server Management Studio required any kind of back-up. So, I am asking for advice. If the new version can just the databases and the structure back as it is then I have no need to take any back-ups. Please advise.

Comment: I think you may be confusing SQL Server Management Studio with SQL Server itself.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, SSMS is just a client tool that connects to the SQL server. SQL server Retains all the information including SA login and password.
You can remove, re-install the client tool without affecting any SQL Server or Database settings.

Note that You will need to re-enter the login and password (in your case SA login and Password) to connect to the database in your new SSMS client tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot @John. I will go ahead with the same.